# How to reload image preview in WPF (Visual Studio Design editor) after image local modification

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I use visual Studio 2013 for a WPF project. The project already have a lot images that has been added with Image control.
All images are loaded from images of the project avalaible in a folder *./images/all_project_images_are_here*

My issue is that when I modify locally an image with paint (or another editor), image in my Visual Studio editor is not reloaded.

**Is there a way to force image to be reloaded in the design view?**

I do not want to restart Visual Studio every time I modify an image...

For example :

Initial image in "./images" folder (128*128, white background): [image: localImageBefore]

Image in my Xaml file :

`<Image x:Name="imgParamFlip_Horizontal" Height="30" Width="30" Source="images/image_flip.png" Margin="0"/>`

Image in my editor (Design view)[image: Image_inEditor_WPF_before_after]

Image after modification in local (cropped to 80*80, set yellow background) : [image: ImageAfterlocalModification]

Image after local modification in my editor (Design view)[image: Image_inEditor_WPF_before_after] --> *Nothing has changed in Visual studio Design view even if source file was modified*

**Is there a way to force visual studio to reload the image?**

Comment: In VS 2019 changes made on resources are visible in Design View after compilation of the project where images are added, but I don't know if it will work in your case.

Comment: How about closing the window/page , clean and rebulit the project , then reopen your window/page to check if it is work or not?